# Php email form on nginx

Tags: php, html, forms, nginx, fastcgi

I have a static html page that has a php form to send an email, the server is nginx and site loads as expected however when I attempt to send an email via the form I get a 404 error,
in the console; `POST http://example.com/form-handler.php 404 (Not Found)`

and the nginx error.log;

> 2014/04/07 14:31:19 [error] 10199#0: *48 open()
>   "/home/deployer/example/current/404.html" failed (2: No such file or
>   directory), client: 86.131.120.178, server: example.com, request:
>   "POST /form-handler.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer:
>   "http://example.com/"

this is my nginx conf for the site;

```
 server {
            listen   80;

            root /home/deployer/example/current;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;

            server_name example.com www.example.com;

            location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            }

            error_page 404 /404.html;

            error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                  root /usr/share/nginx/www;
            }
            location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
          expires 365d;
        }
            # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include fastcgi_params;

            }

    }
```

I don't know why it cant find the form...

Comment: Do yo mean that the script runs fine if you simply type the URL in your browser's location bar?

Comment: no, it can't find the php page form-handler.php

Comment: Well, that clearly discards any specific issue related to the POST method. Now, can you run a simple test PHP script that e.g. prints 'hello'?

Comment: I know next to nothing about php...

Comment: I tried a page with <?php
phpinfo();
?> but I still get a 404